# Angular [routerLink] set context path

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Is it possible to set global application context path for all links globally?

For example, given my applicaton context path is `http://host/client1` I would like 
`<a [routerLink]="'mypath'"></a>` to take me to `http://host/client1/mypath`. If it's not possible with `[routerLink]`, then I would request for suggestions how to write my own directive that extends router link but has this functionality?

Also something to note about the use case. The routing in the application is

```
[
  {
    path: ':clientid',
    children: [
      // Application routes
    ]
  }
]
```

Meaning that this context path should be dynamic

We're using `angular/cli 8.3`

Comment: how frequent you will use it? I would suggest you to have the `clientId` based on the logged in user in app headers or localStorage or sessionStorage, having that information on `router params` is not secure

Comment: @Aravind absolutely everywhere. `clientId` does not represent user, more like a shop that user views. This has nothing to do with sessions or security. Desired effect is to reach certain shop through link

Comment: okay makes sense. so you can use it in the parent route in the app module `:clientId`